# using an if statement to check if NaN

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm getting a numeric value from a form. Then I check to see if it's NaN. If it is a number I want to set that value to a variable. The problem is that when I enter a valid number I still get an alert and the number isn't passed to the variable "date". How should I modify my statement so that when it is a valid number I can assign it to the variable date?

```
var adate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;    

    if ( adate == NaN || " ") {
    alert("Please enter a due date");
    return;
    }

    else {
    var date = (new Date()).setDate(adate);
    }

    processDate(date);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("dueDate").value` will allways be a string (maybe `undefined` in some corner cases), so you should first try to convert it to your needed data type before checking for NaN.

Comment: I would make it a number first with `parseInt(adate)` and then check for `NaN`.

Answer (score 19):

Use Javascript's [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function.

Checking equality with NaN is always false, as per IEEE's standards.
Stephen Canon, a member of the IEEE-754 committee that decided this, has [an excellent answer explaining this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/1253844).

Comment: Isn't isNAN() ECMA6 only?

Comment: `Number.isNaN` is ES6, `isNaN` is a builtin function present since 1st standard definition.

Answer (score 10):

As strange as it seems, `NaN !== NaN`.

```
if (adate !== adate || adate !== " ") {
  //...
}
```

The `isNaN` function would work in a lot of cases. [There is a good case to be made that it is broken, though](https://gist.github.com/kitcambridge/1086528).

One nice way of getting around this is:

```
MyNamespace.isNaN = function (x) {
  return x !== x;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you could Use `if( isNaN(adate))`

good luck

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here. The result is that the conditional will always pass. This is what it does:

```
adate == NaN // first, test if adate == NaN (this always returns false)
||           // if the first test fails (i.e. always), carry on checking
" "          // test if the string " " is truthy (this always returns true)
```

The `||` does two separate checks. It does *not* test to see if `adate` is "either `NaN` or `" "`", which seems to be what you expect.

Your code might as well say

```
if ( true ) {
```

You would be able to sort this out, however, if you tried two comparisons:

```
if ( (adate == NaN) || (adate === " ")) {
```

As other people have said, however, this doesn't work, because `NaN !== NaN`. So the solution is to use `isNaN`:

```
if (isNaN(adate) || (adate === " ")) {
```

Comment: thanks for clearing me up on isNaN vs NaN and the correct meaning of || . I ended up using if (isNaN(adate) ||(0 == adate.length) || adate == 0) . Which I'm not sure is the best way to go about it yet. I may end up doing what @Yoshi was talking about and try to parse the values first before running this check

Answer (score 1):

***By using isNaN method we can verify if the given input is number or not.***

```js
let num1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter your number-1'));
let num2 = parseInt(prompt('Enter your number-2'));
alert(num1 + " is of type " + typeof num1 + " & " + num2 + " is of type " + typeof num2);
if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
  alert("Can not add incompatible types");
} else {
  let sum = num1 + num2;
  alert("Sum is " + sum);
}
```